# Assigning a variable to the value of style property not working

Tags: javascript

I must be overlooking something, but the below code is not working for me (sorry for something so basic):

```
(function(){
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var test = "rgb(" + parseInt((9.3 * Math.random())) + "," + parseInt((9.1 * Math.random())) + "," + parseInt((102 * Math.random())) + ");";
        this.style.backgroundColor = test;
        console.log(test); // corretly outputs rgb(12, 20, 30)
    }, false);
})();
```

Using a string as the value works and assigning a variable to a string containing an rgb value also works, but using `test` as the value doesn't work, and doesn't show any console errors. Why is this?

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not correctly output  `rgb(12, 20, 30)`, it outputs  `rgb(12, 20, 30);`

You are setting

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(12, 20, 30);";
```

There is a semicolon which is causing the value to be invalid. You need to remove the semicolon from the string

```
+ ");";
    ^
```

It should be

```
+ ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass `;` at the end

```
var test = 
    "rgb(" 
    + parseInt((9.3 * Math.random())) 
    + "," 
    + parseInt((9.1 * Math.random())) 
    + "," 
    + parseInt((102 * Math.random())) + ")";
```

Remove `;` from `+ ");"`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YKqj/)

Answer (score 0):

Also your colour range is not big enough to notice a difference, 12, 30 and 7 will look similar. try this:

```
(function () {
    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255),
            g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255),
            b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    });
})();
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/7zNv6/